# How to make clicking on a radio button equal in behaviour to clicking on its container?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I have a bunch of radio-buttons wrapped into div-s, label-s and others. A simplified version would be this:

```
<div>
  <label for="rb__1">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__1" onclick="onRadioButtonClick(event)" value="some_val__1" />
   <span style="....">my rb__1</span>
  </label>
</div>


<div>
  <label for="rb__2">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__2" onclick="onRadioButtonClick(event)" value="some_val__2" />
   <span style="....">my rb__2</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label for="rb__3">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__3" onclick="onRadioButtonClick(event)" value="some_val__3" />
   <span style="....">my rb__3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Handler:

```
   <script>
    function onRadioButtonClick(event) {
       /* handler; it may read 'value' of the current radio-button and other things */  
    }
   </script>
```

I want to add `onclick` handler to each `div` as well such that clicking on it would result to the same behaviour: an appropriate radio button would become selected and handled the same way as if a click occured on a radio button itself. And all of this with a smallest amount of copy-paste possible.

I can't simply add `onclick`  on a `div` because there're things that a handler reads from `event` and that are specific to a radio button.

And I don't want unneccesary `if (clickOnDiv) then... else if (clickOnRadio) then...` either.

How to do it in a proper way?

Comment: Which things does a handler read from `event`?

Comment: `and other things`, like what specifically?

Comment: if there are "things that the handler reads" from the radio button click that clicking the div won't fire, then you can't expect clicking the div to be the same.

Comment: ***I want to add onclick handler to each div as well such that clicking on it would result to the same behaviour*** ~ If you use an event listener on a div that has multiple children, how can you expect to not have conditionals to check which child element is being clicked and triggering the event?

Answer (score 0):

You use id and for attributes. id attribute gives your input type an id and for attribute on label finds any input matching the same name. If their name match, you get the desired result.

Also in a group all radio buttons should have the same value for name attribute otherwise, you will be able to select multiple items.

I am not adding the toggle functionality to the radio button but you can do that using JavaScript.

```html
<input type="radio" id="radio-button" name="radio">
<label for="radio-button" class="radio-btn-1">Radio Button</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio-button-2" name="radio">
<label for="radio-button-2" class="radio-btn-2">Radio Button 2</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using div tag as top level, i would suggest you to use `label` element.

Value of `for` property of `label` and `id` property of `input` tag must be same. So when user clicks on label, corresponding radio element will be selected/unselected and an `onchange` event will be fired.

```js
function onRadioButtonClick(e){
  console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

```html
<label for="rb__1">
    <input id="rb__1" type="radio" name="rb__1" onchange="onRadioButtonClick(event)" value="some_val__1" />
    <span style="....">my rb__1</span>
</label>

<label for="rb__2">
    <input id="rb__2" type="radio" name="rb__2" onchange="onRadioButtonClick(event)" value="some_val__2" />
    <span style="....">my rb__1</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `div` elements as listeners for a click event, you will have to have conditionals to check the event being fired, being three potential elements other than the input => `LABEL`, `SPAN` or `DIV`.

Each of these will have to be handled differently using the event *especially if you want separate things that will be **relative** to the **element** the **event** actually is*. The ***div*** and ***label*** we can simply *query* the **input** selector as it will be a child, whereas the ***span*** we have to target the **parent** and then get its ***first*** **child**, so the conditional will be different than the proceeding two.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')

function selectInput(e) {
  $this = e.target;
  let input = $this.querySelector('input[type="radio"]')  
  $this.tagName === "DIV" ?
    input.checked === true ?
    input.checked = false :
    input.checked = true :
    null;
  $this.tagName === "LABEL" ?
    input.checked === true ?
    input.checked = false :
    input.checked = true :
    null;
  $this.tagName === "SPAN" ?
    $this.parentNode.children[0].checked === true ?
    $this.parentNode.children[0].checked = false :
    $this.parentNode.children[0].checked = true :
    null;
  console.log($this.tagName)
}

parent.forEach(div => div.addEventListener('click', selectInput))
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <label for="rb__1">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__1" value="some_val__1" />
   <span style="....">my rb__1</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <label for="rb__2">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__2" value="some_val__2" />
   <span style="....">my rb__2</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <label for="rb__3">
   <input type="radio" name="rb__3" value="some_val__3" />
   <span style="....">my rb__3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```